# "Namespaced" methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby, namespaces, grouping, sections

There is a class with "namespaced" methods:

```
class MyOrder
  def add
  end

  def edit
  end
end

class MyCompany
  def list
  end
end

class MyDriver
  def add
  end

  def edit
  end
end

class MyAPI
  attr_reader :order, :company, :driver

  def initialize
    @order = MyOrder.new
    @company = MyCompany.new
    @driver = MyDriver.new
  end
end
```

The idea is to group methods into sections to call them like:

```
api = MyApi.new
api.order.add
api.company.list
```

Is there some way to group methods without creating container classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MyAPI
  def initialize
    @namespace = []
  end
  def self.namespace sym
    define_method(sym){@namespace.push(sym); self}
  end
  namespace :order
  namespace :company
  namespace :driver
  def add
    case @namespace
    when [:order] then ...
    when [:driver] then ...
    else raise "invalid namespace"
    end
    @namespace = []
    self
  end
  def edit
    case @namespace
    when [:order] then ...
    when [:driver] then ...
    else raise "invalid namespace"
    end
    @namespace = []
    self
  end
  def list
    case @namespace
    when [:company] then ...
    else raise "invalid namespace"
    end
    @namespace = []
    self
  end
end
```

The `self` at the end of the methods is to let you be able to do chaining like

```
MyApi.new.order.add.company.list
```

If you don't need to do this, then `self` is unnecessary.

Comment: Interesting approach, but grouping by method and chaining decrease readability. What I am seeking for is for example a bunch of complex-named methods like `order_add` which are called by dynamically concatenated name. Is this possible?

Comment: That is an entirely different question. You didn't ask so. It is possible.

Comment: This is only one variant which came into my mind. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I see, try the following:

```
module MyApi
  [MyOrder, MyCompany, MyDriver].each do |klass|    
    names = klass.to_s.scan(/[A-Z][a-z]+/)

    funcname = names[1].downcase
    define_singleton_method(funcname) do 
      instance_variable_get("@#{funcname}") ||
      instance_variable_set("@#{funcname}", klass.new)
    end
  end
end

MyApi.order.add
```

If you prefer to order_add, then:

```
module MyApi
  [MyOrder, MyCompany, MyDriver].each do |klass|    
    names = klass.to_s.scan(/[A-Z][a-z]+/)

    prefix_name = names[1].downcase

    klass.public_instance_methods(false).each do |method|
      funcname = "#{prefix_name}_#{method}"
      define_singleton_method(funcname) do |*args|
        @obj = instance_variable_get("@#{prefix_name}") ||
               instance_variable_set("@#{prefix_name}", klass.new)
        @obj.send(method, *args)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Your code was a thing which I started with. Then I minimized it to one initializer and several attr_readers because of more compact code. In real life there are 25 sections in this class and their amount will grow.